# How to create a navigation side menu?

Tags: javascript, html

I just want to add a side menu that links to various pages on my site. I would like to use image buttons or simple hrefs that the user clicks on to navigate. I think I need to use a div somehow ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please be a little more specific about how we can help?

Comment: I just want a list of items to the left of my page, and when clicked navigation takes place to a different page. The navigations items can be just simple text or buttons. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `div` element and float it left with CSS.

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://example.com/page2">A Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://example.com/page3">Another Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <p> Here's some stuff </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    background-color: gray;
}

#content {
    width: 80%;
}
```

I would also run through the HTML and CSS tutorials at [HTML Dog](http://htmldog.com/). It will make your life so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Listamatic has various examples of [how to style a list of links](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```
<!Doctype html>
<html projectReviver="leftmenu.html">
  <head>
    <title>My Left Menu</title>
    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="design.css" type="text/css" />
    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div id="main">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="page.html">First page</a></li>
          <li><a href="page2.html">2<sup>nd</sup>page</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </nav>
    </body>
  </html>
```

design.css :

```css
#mainu ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: red;
}
#nav {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}
#content {
  list-style: none;
}
```